# I'm running a cgo application in an Android environment, and it crashes at _cgo_topofstack. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm running a cgo application in an Android environment, and it crashes at `_cgo_topofstack`.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0  00000000  r1  000028f3  r2  0000000b  r3  00000008
    r4  00002829  r5  92589500  r6  92589548  r7  0000010c
    r8  00000007  r9  f2dda124  r10 92589400  r11 bc3218ca
    ip  bf21e9cc  sp  eeb7fc00  lr  bb39d2f8  pc  bb3c07d8

backtrace:
      #00 pc 0049a7d8  /data/app/~~RaMB3k_xm7v41sDHB5G52Q==/com.tencent.supercar-Qe2_Smo7BnMcTvBrMSmgRA==/lib/arm/libtskm.so
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VMZi.png)

```
# ./arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line result:
_cgo_topofstack
??:?
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to figure out why it crashes at _cgo_topofstack